# 未ログイン時のvoteについて何か送信しているのでしょうか？

Tags: サポート, 翻訳

未ログイン時のvoteとコメントで表示の差異が気になりました。
`送信しています`とありますが、アクションのログか何か送信しているのでしょうか？

vote

> ＞原文
>   Sending feedback...
>   Thanks for the feedback!
>   ＞訳
>   フィードバックを送信しています...
>   フィードバックをお寄せいただき、ありがとうございました！

コメント

> ＞原文
>   Loading...
>   Your feedback is appreciated!
>   ＞訳
>   読み込んでいます...
>   フィードバックありがとうございます！

同じ"フィードバック"を使うなら統一した方が良さそうに感じており、
動作的に違うのなら問題ないのかも…とも考えています。
(……個人的にはフィードバックと言われたときにニュアンスとして"評価"/"反応"よりも"意見"が強くて「何か送信されてしまったのかな？」と感じることが多いです。もし分けられるなら「投票いただきありがとうございます」などアクション名を入れたい気もします。)

Comment: たしか、[SO のデータベース](http://data.stackexchange.com/ja/queries)上には、「未登録ユーザーからのFB」データがあったはず。 その見方についてはちょっと覚えていないですが。。

Comment: ありがとうございます。ただ、頂いたリンクから探しきれませんでした。また、"コメントの投稿"でも扱いがFeedBackになっているのでここでいうFeedBackの中身が分からないと送信していることが分かりませんね……。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stack Exchange全体のメタQ&Aにある情報を総合すると:

### 投票した時

- 未登録ユーザーもしくは匿名ユーザーとして投票すると、その情報がデータベースに保存されます
- ただし信用度、バッジ、その他通常見える範囲では何も影響を与えません
- SEデータエクスプローラーと、10kユーザーがアクセス可能な統計情報ページから確認可能

データベース上では `PostFeedback` テーブルに保存されています。登録ユーザーからの投票は別のテーブルで、 `Votes` テーブルです。

**未登録ユーザー** (unregistered user) とは: 回答を「ゲストとして投稿」すると未登録ユーザーとなります。ブラウザのクッキーに保存された情報でしか認証をおこなえないので、別のブラウザからは同じユーザーとしてアクセスできません。正式にユーザー登録すると同じユーザーとしてアクセスできます。

**匿名ユーザー** (anonymous user) とは: 未登録ユーザーでも、登録ユーザーでもない状態のこと。

`PostFeedback.IsAnonymous` が `0` の場合、未登録ユーザーからの投票、 `1` であれば匿名ユーザーからの投票になります。

### コメントした時

- コメント情報がデータベースに保存されます
- コメントするには一定の信用度が必要なので<sup>1</sup>、匿名ユーザーとしてコメントすることはできません

データベース上では `Comments` テーブルに保存されています。 `Comments.UserId` カラムで `Users` テーブルとの紐付けができますが、 登録・未登録の区別はデータエクスプローラーからは取得できません。

<sup>1 自分の質問や回答へのコメントには信用度の制限はありませんが、匿名ユーザーは質問・回答をおこなえないので、やはりコメントするには登録ユーザーもしくは未登録ユーザーである必要があります。</sup>

#### 参考

- [ユーザーの手でメンテされているデータベーススキーマ情報](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/157841)
- [PostFeedbackテーブルの用途は？](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194939/157841)
- [要望: SEDEのデータにユーザー種別を追加してほしい](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196835/please-add-usertype-to-stack-exchange-data-explorer/252252)
- [SEデータエクスプローラー: 最近寄せられた未登録・匿名ユーザーからの投票](http://data.stackexchange.com/ja/query/724025/recent-votes-from-unregistered-or-anonymous-users)
- [SEデータエクスプローラー: 未登録ユーザーっぽい表示名のユーザーからのコメント](http://data.stackexchange.com/ja/query/725737/comments-from-users-with-display-names-that-look-like-unregistered)

Comment: なるほど、詳細な情報ありがとうございます。投票については理解しました。文言については特におかしい点はなさそうですね。では、コメントについてはどうでしょうか？こちらも記録されているものなのでしょうか？

Comment: @Myaku コメントについて追記しました。こちらの場合の「フィードバック」は違和感ありますか？

Comment: 追記ありがとうございます。信用度がないユーザ(匿名ユーザなど含む)のコメント操作は記録されていないのですね。自分のもののコメント履歴に関してもユーザレコードが無いとなので"送信している"旨の表記がないと…なるほど。個人的に表示の差異が気になったのですが内部の仕様として違うならこの表示で納得できるかと思います。(仕様を知らない人がどう感じるかについては別スレになりそうですが、私としては理解したので一旦閉めます)